# Commutator subgroup of the absolute Galois group - a closed subgroup

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, profinite-groups, number-fields, absolute-galois-group

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Is it possible that the commutator subgroup of the absolute Galois group of $K$ (considered as an abstract group) is a closed subgroup? This property holds for the absolute Galois groups of $p$-adic fields because they are topologically finitely generated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the abstract commutator subgroup $[G_K,G_K]$ of the absolute Galois group $G_K$ of a number field $K$ is never closed:

Write $[G,G]$ for the commutator subgroup of $G$ as an abstract group,
and $c(G)$ for the commutator width of $G$,
i.e. the minimal $n$ such that every element in $[G,G]$ is a product of at most $n$ commutators.
From the Baire category theorem one gets that

$(*)$ the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ of a profinite group $G$ is closed if and only if $c(G)$ is finite.

Moreover, for a profinite group $G$ one clearly has

$(**)$ $c(G) = \sup_{N\lhd_c G} c(G/N)$

i.e. the commutator width is the supremum of the commutator width of the (continuous) finite quotients.

So in order to show that $c(G_K)=\infty$ (and hence $[G_K,G_K]$ is not closed) it would suffice to exhibit a family of finite quotients of $G_K$ of unbounded commutator width. One such family is the family of finite $p$-groups, for a fixed prime $p$:

(1) By a celebrated theorem of Shafarevich [1], every such group (in fact every finite solvable group) is the Galois group of a finite Galois extension of $K$.

(2) By a result of Roman'kov (Theorem 2 in [2]), there exists a finitely generated pro-$p$ group $F$ whose (abstract) second commutator group $F^{(2)}$ is not closed. By $(*)$ that means that the commutator subgroup $F'=[F,F]$ has $c(F')=\infty$. Therefore, by $(**)$, the family of finite quotients of $F'$, all of which are $p$-groups, has unbounded commutator width.
EDIT: For a direct and short proof of this see the comment of YCor below.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shafarevich%27s_theorem_on_solvable_Galois_groups

[2] https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01987820.pdf

Comment: I should add that I'm not a group theorist and there is a chance I am interpreting the results of [2] incorrectly. Maybe an expert on the topic can check me on this.

Comment: I don't know the reference (2), but the fact that the family of $p$-groups has unbounded commutator width, for fixed $p$ (say odd) is very easy, and even the family of $p$-groups of nilpotency class $2$ and exponent $p$. Indeed, let $G_n$ be the free group in this variety. It has $p^n$ elements mod the center and $p^{n(n-1)/2}$ elements in the derived subgroups. So it has at most $p^{kn}$ products of $k$ commutators, which is $<p^{n(n-1)/2}$ as long as $k<(n-1)/2$, i.e., for $n>2k+1$ it has commutator width $\ge k$.

Comment: @YCor: Great, thanks, I was hoping there would be a more direct argument. Just to make sure, do I understand correctly that this $G_n$ can be described as the free group $F_n$ modulo the subgroup generated by $p$-th powers and elements of the form $[[x,y],z]$? Is there a more explicit description of $G_n$?

Comment: Yes exactly (for prime $p$ odd). It can be defined as a Lie algebra $V\oplus\Lambda^2(V)$ with $V$ $n$-dimensional over the field $\mathbf{F}_p$, with product $[v,w]=v\wedge w$ for $v,w\in V$ and $\Lambda^2(V)$ central, and group law $x\ast y=x+y+\frac12[x,y]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll add a remark to the answer.